# Tightening Zhang's bound

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Inspired by a [blogpost](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/i-just-cant-resist-there-are-infinitely-many-pairs-of-primes-at-most-59470640-apart) by Scott Morrison and ongoing discussion there I decided to create this community wiki to track progress on the original bound of Yitan Zhang.

The [original](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/YitangZhang.pdf) bound was $70,000,000$. The accepted answer should contain latest known improvement.

---

As of 4.6. 2013 there is a polymath project devoted to improving this bound. The proposal can be found at http://polymathprojects.org/2013/06/04/polymath-proposal-bounded-gaps-between-primes/

Links to various references: http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes

A good place to start is to read [notes](http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/bounds.pdf) by Terence Tao and his [blog post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/the-prime-tuples-conjecture-sieve-theory-and-the-work-of-goldston-pintz-yildirim-motohashi-pintz-and-zhang/) on the topic.

Comment: Good, informative, description! Couple typos: the name Terence has only one 'r', and in Records it should be 'Richards', not 'Richardson'.

Comment: I voted the question down because I think that the question/answer format of MathOverflow is not right medium for this kind of collaboration.

Comment: Perhaps that's a conversation to be had on meta?

Comment: I have an impression that this topic is more suitable for Polymath project: http://polymathprojects.org/

Comment: Meta thread - http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1605/tightening-zhangs-bound/

Comment: Regarding $\omega$, Zhang is not tight in this area. Zhang's work is sufficiently comparable to previous work (FI and BFI) that unwinding it is reasonably feasible. For instance, the point of 13 and 14 is to get $x^{1-\epsilon}/d$ and he shows $x^{1-\omega/3}/d$ (13.4), which by (13.5) is $x^{1-\omega/2+2\epsilon}$. He often boosts $\omega$ to offset an $\epsilon$, this is not needed. You also have the measure the $d$-range. As a style comment, I would prefer him to have written it like BFI, as it would be then easier to figure out how to optimize params.

Comment: Here is the gist of $r$ in 13.12, you want it small for 3 various bounds 14.4 14.5 14.8 with congruence sums (take mod $r$), want it big since you win by $\sqrt r$ in the Kloosterman result (get $q^{3/2}r$ rather than both $3/2$). But you have to beat back the $H$ and $K$ you introduced from Fourier (see 10.17, though it doesn't say everything). This is the balancing with $\omega$ which is not made transparent.

Comment: Prior to 13&14 where I think Zhang can be reworked, he uses $3/8+8\omega<1/2-32\omega$ or $\omega<1/320$ at the end of S6. Again you might do better by enhancing (is 8 multiplier mandatory this large?), but I feel this closer to a true value.

Comment: Regarding $1-\omega/2$ versus $31/32+36\omega$, as I say this is arbitrarily imposed. He only need to beat $1-\epsilon$, not $1-\omega/2$, and similarly the 36 has seen some easiness with $\omega$'s on convenience. The right precept is to balance the losses, but writing format does this not separately. The choice of $K$ at 13.15 is not optimate but convenient, to ease next lines (and it is not 48 but 45+2+eps). Now $K$ is high to import the Weyl shifting gains (sharpen diagonal, see before 14.9 as $K^2$ vs $K$), low to lighten Fourier losses. But I agree, $H$ is minimal as possible directly.

Comment: @v08ltu, it looks like a polymath project is starting up, and this is exactly the sort of analysis needed.

Could I suggest you post your comments either on a blog (if you have access to one), or at the polymath proposal blog http://polymathprojects.org/2013/06/04/polymath-proposal-bounded-gaps-between-primes, or at one of the other blogs posts which is sure to appear soon?

Comment: Maybe now I see $K$ is nearly maximal as possible with Fourier losses, as main term for S14 has $K$ cancel out anyway. Why Zhang does $1/4-21\omega$ equals $3/16+52\omega$ to demand the situation? Just keep the former, account: you need to save $16\omega$ from $N_1^2$ and $4\omega$ with $d_1d_1$, so $\sqrt r$ should be at least $20\omega$ in exponent. Then $K$ as is but with 42, $3/16+46\omega<1/4-19\omega$ I get $\omega\sim 1/1040$. Not checked, to propose a design just this is.


Comment: Oh I could be all wet and drawled, what I did was to take minimum with $r$, but can consign the upper bounds too, possibly increase (much greater value). But I agree, Polymath would be best. I have seen few blogs, which do more than talk to the press and review GY before saying "and $\sqrt$ was broken" Albeit, the result was straight up an expert's alley, but the new material should be more prevalent. Zhang is decent in his intro, but should amplify demonstrative gains more.


Comment: (Thanks Vit! Looks like I didn't need to do much after all.)

Comment: Do you, or anyone, intend to update this evetually say via adding a new answer. It seems to me a lot of things happened in the interim. If this is not updated I fail to see the point of having this. (Yes I can follow the link to the chronology, but just this a bit too little in my opinion.)

Comment: This post is extremely out of date (and was not really ontopic to begin with). Voted to close.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has a moving target. The current answer is horribly out of date (see http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes).

Comment: This question, made CW with a view to posting regular updates on the status of progress to improve Zhang's bound, is dying due to inattention, and so will now be closed.

Answer (score 10):

### Original approach

A set of integers $H$ is called *admissible* if it avoids at least one residue class modulo $p$ for each prime $p$. In other words
$$
\forall p \in \mathcal{P} :\text{cardinality of} \, \lbrace x \bmod p \, | \, x \in H \rbrace \leq p-1.
$$

Let $Q(k_0)$ denote the assertion that for any admissible set $H$ of cardinality $k_0$ there are infinitely many translates $n+H$ that contain at least two primes. The bound on the gap is then $\mathrm{diam}\, H$.

Zhang deduces his bound from the following result:

**T1:** $Q(3,500,000)$ is true

In Zhang's paper the length $k_0$ is determined by the following inequality (1) that has to hold for some natural number $l_0$

$$
(1+4\varpi) (1-\kappa_2) > \left(1 + \frac{1}{2l_0+1}\right) \left(1 + \frac{2l_0+1}{k_0}\right) (1+\kappa_1),
$$
where

$$
\kappa_1 = \delta_1 \left( 1 + \delta_2^2 + k_0 \log\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{4\varpi} \Bigr) \right) \binom{k_0+2l_0}{k_0}
$$

$$
\kappa_2 = \delta_1 (1+4\varpi) \left(1 +\delta_2^2 + k_0 \log\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{4\varpi} \Bigr) \right) \binom{k_0+2l_0+1}{k_0-1}
$$

$$
\varpi = 1/1168
$$

and

$$
\delta_1 = (1+1/4\varpi)^{-k_0}
$$

$$
\delta_2 = \sum_{j=0}^{1/4\varpi} \frac{k_0\log(1+\frac{1}{4\varpi}))^j}{j!}.
$$

The admissible set that Zhang uses is $H = \{ p_{k_0+1}, \ldots, p_{2k_0}\}.$

### Current record

Terence Tao & Scott Morrison: 4,802,222

Terence Tao [established](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/the-prime-tuples-conjecture-sieve-theory-and-the-work-of-goldston-pintz-yildirim-motohashi-pintz-and-zhang/) another inequality on $k_0$ that manages to remove most of inefficiency of Zhang estimate.
$$
1+4\varpi > \left(1 + \frac{1}{2l_0+1}\right) \left(1 + \frac{2l_0+1}{k_0}\right) (1+\kappa)
$$
where
$$
\kappa := \sum_{1 \leq n < 2 + \frac{1}{2\varpi}} \Bigl(1 - \frac{2n \varpi}{1 + 4\varpi}\Bigr)^{k_0/2 + l_0} \prod_{j=1}^{n} \left(1 + 3k_0 \log\Bigl(1+\frac{1}{j}\Bigr)\right).
$$
Moreover $l_0$ is allowed to be real number. Scott Morrison then found that for $l_0 = 291.7$ one gets $k_0 = 341,640$ which is the best possible $k_0$ for given $\varpi = 1/1168$.

[Paper by Richards](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1974-80-03/S0002-9904-1974-13434-8/S0002-9904-1974-13434-8.pdf) suggest to take as admissible set $H_m = \{ \pm 1, \pm p_{m+1}, \ldots, \pm p_{m+k_0/2+1} \}$ for $m$ large enough. This leads to bound 
$$
2p_{m+\lceil k_0/2 \rceil + 1} \quad \text{for }  k_0  \text{ even}
$$
and 
$$
p_{m+\lfloor{k_0/2}\rfloor-1} + p_{m+\lfloor{(k_0+1)/2}\rfloor-1} \text{ for } k_0 \text{ odd.}
$$
For given $k_0=341,640$ program written by Scott Morrison found that $m=5553$ gives the smallest bound of $4,802,222$.

Comment: Maybe we should try to have a reasonably good chronology of improvements in this or another answer? 

Comment: There is a good chronology at http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes

Comment: Here is a nice brief description by [Gergely Harcos](http://www.math.utexas.edu/users/gharcos/gaps.pdf) of the skeleton of the argument.